# TinyMCE in CMS made simple

Tags: content-management-system, tinymce

Sorry for my bad english!

when I create new page, there is no tinymce window to type content, like on this picture.
http://wiki.cmsmadesimple.org/images/1/19/Admin_content.png

modules folder have got 777 privilegies.
Try to reinstall this module, does not work.
Set up default options configuration for my user - does not work.

What i must to do?

Comment: can you please post your tinymce configuration (the tinymce.init function) ?

Comment: there is no {content} tag in my template - that's was my problem =)

Answer (score 1):

You need to put {content} tag on you page.

Remeber that you can set several content blocks. New versions don't let you use a template without a default {content} tag.